# Why is git pushing unnecessary folders to my repo?

Tags: git, file, github, push, git-push

When I do a git push for one folder in my documents, somehow, all of my folders/files in my Projects folder are pushed. I'm making sure that when I run the 'git push' command, my path is in the folder that I want. For instance:

> PS C:\Users\19802\Documents\Projects\digital_rolodex>

I'm moved the files out of the documents so that they're not pushed and they still keep getting pushed. Every time I set up a new repo, the folders are still pushed, even though the repo was deleted and the folders were removed.
I've deleted the repo and started over twice nice and it keeps doing the same thing, saying they were pushed days ago. I've made sure to change branches, tried that, this didn't help. I've removed them from my commits and source control, these files keep getting pushed to every new repo I create.

I can't find any documents on the internet about this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It means you've added files within them and committed those files.

Comment: Please don't (only) post text as images, and fix your post to comply.

Comment: Git knows nothing of folders, and pushes know nothing of files. You push _commits_. And every commit contains your _whole_ project.

Comment: Git doesn't *store* directories, but the metadata for a blob object includes a path. That means it can preserve the directory hierarchy for tracked files, but cannot store an empty directory itself. (IIRC)

Comment: `push` doesn't really even look at the working directory; it transfers commits you've already created using `add` and `commit`.

Comment: Note that every commit, in a Git repository, holds a *full snapshot of every file*. In other words each commit acts like an archive (tar or rar or winzip or whatever). The act of checking out a commit (with `git checkout` or `git switch`) tells Git: *First, remove from my working tree all the files you have from any previous checkout. Then replace, in my working tree, all the files that come out of the commit I have selected.* You then edit any of those working tree files, add and/or remove some, and run `git add` and/or `git rm` to prepare the *next* commit. [continued]

Comment: When you then run `git commit`, Git packages up the files in Git's *index* aka *staging area* (which starts out holding the same files as Git put into your working tree during the checkout, and is updated by those `git add` / `git rm` commands). That becomes the new *snapshot*, and that snapshot goes into the new commit. When you view a commit with `git show`, Git compares the snapshot *in* that commit to the snapshot in the *previous* (parent) commit and shows you what's different. When you view a commit on line, what you see depends on the on-line generator.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @torek, I think with this information, I'll be able to try and proceed forward to see if there helps. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`git push` doesn't push *folders*; it pushes *commits*.

Your branch apparently contains commits with changes to the files in question, and they are therefore pushed.

If you want to push just changes to one folder, you would have needed to create a branch that contains commits that only modify files in that folder.

Comment: I tried doing this, added a new branch and checking out to this branch, and it did the same thing, pushed up files and folders I don't want on my repo.

Comment: @ecce Then delete your *local* repo and start over. Consider finding the `.git` directory and removing it, or running `git init` in a new folder and only copying the files you're interested in.

Comment: @ecce, I suspect you branched from a branch that contained the files. When you use dir/ls/whatever, do you see the files you don't want to push? The answer should be no.* If you do, you've done something wrong. If you don't want the other folder to be in the repo at all, follow 229044's advice.

Comment: I deleted my repo, created a new report. I deleted my located, started completely over and created a new init using npm init -y. I added the dependencies needed for the project. I checked out to a new branch. I discarded all untracked files in the source control. I did git add ., git commit, git push to a brand new repo. And it still added folders and files from days ago

Comment: You're just adding more to the repo. Not sure why you think that would help.

Comment: Your earlier suggestion isn't working